# How do I accurately resize a map to match the scale of the next map I want to build a bigger map from?

Tags: mapping, scale-factor

I have exported a group of maps that I want to tile together in Illustrator.  Since the maps are not of the same scale I tried calculating the factors between each scale to the largest number of map scale sizes, hoping to multiply the smaller maps to match the alpha map size proportionally.  That thinking did not work in application.
Can I figure out a formula to resize the smaller maps to match the largest map numerically?
I do not want to have to scale using Illustrator's center point-based resize.

Comment: why not just save them all at the same scale? or combine them and then save the final map in one go?

Comment: How do I keep the same scale settings?  Everytime I would get map data the zoom area expands ever-so-slightly.  I would love to hand enter a bar scale value (ex: 1 : 34,758) but I can't find a menu option or field to enter the data.  Is there a setting to lock the zoom bounds?

Comment: that would depend on what mapping software you are using and how you are exporting your maps - use the [edit] link to make changes to your question and the tags